# add fixed value to date

Tags: numbers, addition

I need a function to calculate the difference of dates starting from 1/1/xxxx. We need to have 3 digits which means we need to add 0 in the case of the first three months (number of days less than 100)

currently the code looks like this:

```
Function DM_500()

  If LaserMarker.Drawing.GetMOsByName("KUNDVARNO").Count = 0 Then
    ErrorInLayout("KUNDVARNO")
    Exit Function
  End if

  If LaserMarker.Drawing.GetMOsByName("PDVAR4").Count = 0 Then
    ErrorInLayout("PDVAR4")
    Exit Function
  End if
  



  Set moCstmVaNo        = LaserMarker.Drawing.GetMOsByName("KUNDVARNO").Item(1)
  Set moBarcodeText2    = LaserMarker.Drawing.GetMOsByName("QRCODETEXT1").Item(1)
  Set moBarcodeText1    = LaserMarker.Drawing.GetMOsByName("QRCODETEXT2").Item(1)
  Set moBarcodeText     = LaserMarker.Drawing.GetMOsByName("QRCODETEXT3").Item(1)
  Set moBarcodeOutput   = LaserMarker.Drawing.GetMOsByName("PDVAR4").Item(1) 
   

  StrLength = Len(moCstmVaNo)
  
  'Remember length of customer itemno
  index = strlength 

  'Check length of customer itemno from SAP: customer item no 7 digits + 2 digits of revision no = 9 digits

  strlength = Len(moCstmVaNo)

  IF strLength = 9 Then
  'OK customer itemno incl 2 digits revision no.
  Elseif strLength = 7 Then
  'OK customer itemno 7 digits - excl revision no.
  Else
    strError = "WARNING!!!   WARNING!!!   WARNING!!!" + vbCrLf + vbCrLf 
    strError = strError + "Wrong number of characters in QR Code !!" + vbCrLf + strWorkString
    Msgbox strError 
    Exit Function 
  End if

  'add customer itemno incl. 2 digits of revision no
   CustNo = moCstmVaNo.value   

  'add Supplier id
   SuplyerID = "00019"

  'add Year 2 digits
   YY = Mid(Year(TodayDate),3,2)   


  'add days from 01-01-XXXX to Todays day.
   DayNumber = DateDiff("d", CDate("1/1/" & Year(TodayDate)), TodayDate)+1

  'Add fixt cust name
   CustName = "BDR"
    
      
  'Add Identifier
   Identifier = CHR(124)    ' "|" 124


  'Creating QR code value
   moBarcodeOutput.value = CustName & CustNo & Identifier & SuplyerID & Identifier & YY & DDD & Identifier & "$GSerialNo5$" 


  'Creating the QR code text
   
  moBarcodeText.Value =  YY & DDD & Identifier &  "$GSerialNo5Text$" 
  moBarcodeText1.Value = Identifier & SuplyerID & Identifier
  moBarcodeText2.Value = CustName & CustNo

End Function
```

for example now we have 3 digits
in the case of January, February or March we have 2 digits and must add 0

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] and specify the language involved.

Comment: I'm not sure what I should do

Comment: Provide a complete example rather than just a single line of code, and specify which language you're using. Neither of those should be particularly difficult.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I put the whole code now

Comment: The problem is that DayNumber function because I need to have 3 digits

Comment: You still haven't told us what language this is, and this definitely isn't a *minimal* example. (Do you think your problem *only* exists when creating a QR code? If not, remove the QR-code-specific aspects to it, etc. Is the customer number relevant? I suspect not...)

Comment: It sounds like really your problem is "I have a number and I need to format it as a string with exactly three digits". Demonstrating that problem doesn't require dates or addition etc at all...

Comment: I managed to fix it thanks a lot for your efforts

Comment: I'll delete this post tomorrow